# XeLaTex does not produce pdf with .eps images

Tags: xetex, texstudio, eps, miktex2.9

I experience a problem with XeLaTex and .eps figures. When I compile my .tex file, on the pdf viewer I get a message:

"*does not look like a valid pdf document. Either the file is corrupt or it is in the process of creation. Retrying every two seconds.*"

My example code is the below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\captionsetup{width=0.8\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{examplefig.eps}
\caption{Example of caption}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

I am using MikTex 2.9 with TeXstudio 2.12.16.

[image]

The computer I am using now, and on which the problem occurs, has the MiKTex version below (taken from the .log file):

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
```

while on a second computer where everything works fine with the same configuration I have the below:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (MiKTeX 2.9.6300 64-bit)
```

Any thoughts on how I can possibly solve my issue?

### EDIT 1:

The examplefig.eps I use in my example code was generated and saved from MATLAB. In that case, the fonts do not seem to be embedded. If I try to open the same eps file in Inkscape I get a warning "MiKTeX GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1" which I also in TexStudio. If I save the image from MATLAB in .emf, open it in Inkscape and then export in .eps with embedded fonts then everything in TeXstudio compiles properly. It is weird that no problem occurs with the earlier MiKTex version I mention above. Does anyone ever had a similar experience and how did you manage to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you searched the log file for clues?

Comment: I ran it without `epstopdf` package and it compiled.

Comment: It seems there was recently a reorganisation of the dependencies, and maybe they're not installed. See [this CTANpage](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/epstopdf-pkg).

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen I am afraid I can not figure out if there is any remarkable issue in the log file.

Comment: @tachyon I tried it but still the same. Could you please let me know which version of MiKTex you are using? You can find the exact number in the first line of your log file.

Comment: @Bernard Is there any way to go back to an earlier version?

Comment: Pasting the detailed message: `This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6650) `.

Comment: I really don't know. Did you try the lissing dependencies, if any?

Comment: Try running with `pdfLatex` or `Latex` instead of `Xetex` if there is no other requirement to compile with `Xetex`.

Comment: It may be a problem with that eps, Can you try with another eps.